# Windows Phone 8.1 app Multi language

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating windows phone app 8.1 in SilverLight with Visual Studio 2015. I am creating multi language app in English and Arabic. For that I have created Strings folder in the project with two folder of en-US and ar-KW with Resources.resw file in each folder.

I am **x:Uid** setting properties. For example `Key:- Actual.Text Value:- Actual`

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Actual" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Above is working very good. I have combobox with Item EN and AR. I am triggering SelectionChanged event to change the Language **But the issue is when I stop the app and run it again than only it change the text and layout.**

How can I do it at runtime without restart.

```
private void LanguageComboBoxName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedItem = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
            var RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as SlideApplicationFrame;

            if (selectedItem == "EN")
                ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
            else if (selectedItem == "AR")
                ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ar-KW";

            RootFrame.Navigate(this.GetType());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i remember it is not recommended by Microsoft to change language in a runtime (by overriding it) but you can do it by reloading the page. The easiest way is to put your combobox with the code on another page and there you will override language, so when you navigate back (and page will be reloaded) you will have what you want. Keep in mind that overriding language will not localize controls in the runtime (but it shouldn't be a great issue for you). You must restart the app to localize controls.

When you override language with this code:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "xx-XX";
```

then it is saved and you don't have to override it again on the start. App will load with the overrided language.

Additionally when you localize the app it is good to override culture info because if you have some dates - they are shown properly for the culture (e.g. 12/01/2015 or 01-12-2015)

```
string lang = "en-US";    //default
var culture = new CultureInfo(lang);
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = lang;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

There's one more **important** thing.

In your app manifest or what you have there, you need to set *Generate app bundle* to "Never". The reason is that when you uploaded packaged version to the store then your runtime localization won't work. You may be able to localize your app in the runtime with emulator or debug versions or even sometimes with deployed release versions. But you need to do that so when your app is in the store then there is no problem with localization and all of the string for languages can be accessed (because for packaged version some of them might not be if you haven't installed the language on your phone).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the app to depend on a language through user selection, you'll need to store that selection and read it out on app start.
That way you can change the ApplicationLanguage when the app starts.

So in App.Xaml.cs look for the method `InitializePhoneApplication()` and add following lines ( or you could also try your approach here with ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride )

```
string savedLanguage = string.Empty;
var hasSavedLanguage = AppSettings.TryGetSetting(Constants.LanguageSettingKey, out savedLanguage);
if (hasSavedLanguage)
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(savedLanguage);
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
}
```

Of course you'll also need to save the language when the user selected one from the combobox

Comment: In my whole app I cannot find `InitializePhoneApplication()` method

Comment: It did not work out.  I try to debug the code when it override the language and when I re-navigate. It will not go back to OnLaunched() event

Comment: The onLaunched will only be triggered when the app starts. Do you need something else also? Because in your original question you did say the only problem was when restarting the app.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. I will explain again as I told u when I select AR in the combo box, I am changing Application Primary Language and try to reload the page Arabic resource will load but it is not happening. But when I restart app again that time it will start showing Arabic language and vice-versa for English

Comment: Oh I see now, it's the other way around. You need the page to change at runtime. Will the actual page itself is hard, only thing I can think of is trying to reload it, because the ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride is a correct approach, but you'll need to navigate away from the page that uses it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95536/discussion-between-milind-and-depechie).

Comment: For reference doing it 'on the fly' is explained here: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2012/03/instant-language-update-in-windows.html

Comment: Thanx I will look at it

Comment: Link which you showed did not help as it is for Windows 7 and I am using windows phone 8.1

Comment: Concept is still the same for wp8.1, short version you'll need to use a class with properties that have notifyproperychange for all translations. That way you can change the language and the UI will change too.

Comment: In that Article he is using MVVMLight which is use for MVVM and I am bot using MVVM in my project

Comment: If you are not using MVVM then you'll need to set all the text yourself in code behind when you change the language.