# Mutli Language Windows Phone 8.1 app not working on Windows Store

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have created windows phone 8.1 app with Visual Studio 2015. It is certified and in the store. I make it hidden as it have some issue.
App is in the English and Arabic language. Thing is that when I run the app on the emulator and change language it works great. When I manually install app to device from my visual studio it works perfectly in both language.

But when I uploaded to the windows store and then I install, it did not work. When I change the language than nothing happen, all captions and labels appear in English, it never change the language. What I am missing or what is wrong !!

Please note that Windows Store has detected my app as Arabic and English as I can write description in both language.

Comment: I wrote you here what you have to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34019819/4990487  Now delete the app from the store and create another one because you can't upload other versions of packages than you uploaded first.

Comment: @MichalKozak that is not my issue, My issue is that when I run my app on emulator or if I install app on device manually language change work properly. But if I install app from windows store language change don't works.  I cannot see Arabic translation from resource file when I install from windows store but I can see Arabic translation in my emulator or install manuallly

Comment: What is the name of resource file for arabic?

Comment: If you change the language of the phone then maybe you missed something with country codes: en-US is not the same as en-UK. If you have UK installed on the phone then it's treated as separate language not as english overall. Same could happen to Arabic. But if that's good then maybe you're overriding language of the app somewhere in your code - look for it.

Comment: It is like folder parent folder strings child folder ar-KW and then Resource.resw

Comment: @MichalKozak Nothing is like that, as I told you its work on emulator and when I install manually also works. Just when I install from Windows Store it does not works

Comment: Only current language resource is downloaded on the phone all other resource files are removed. Now your language resource is specif to ar-KW and I think you are not adding default resource file for Arabic to support all other Arabic languages(like -SA, SY etc.). Add another resource folder named ar and in it Resource.resw for all other arabic cultures

Comment: Hi Thank for the reply. Kindly can explain it more properly. Can I get any example for it.

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-localizing-apps/
See section "How it is done in Windows Phone 8.1"

Comment: I have done localization from same website, In a same manner

Comment: so you have ar folder?

Comment: Yes I have strings parent folder than en-US & ar-KW folder than each folder have Resource.resw files

Comment: Now that is the issue. when you select Arabic language other than Kawait application used the default which is en-US. you need to rename your ar-KW folder to only ar

Comment: It should be Strings---->ar--->Resource.resw

Comment: But than why it is working on emulator and when I installing manually from Visual studio it behave very much as we are discussing but when we install it from windows store it did not works

Comment: It is because debugging windows add all the resouce(.resw) file in the app and when you select Ar-XX windows used any arabic languge resource but in app is downloaded from app store it monetize the app

Comment: ok than I will try your suggestion and let you know. As I need to upload to windows store and they have to certified. It will take time

Comment: Before going ahead, I want to make something clear. That is I have app on that app there is Dropdown where two items AR and EN when I select AR app will restart with AR language in debug mode but when I download it from Windows Store my app does not change when I select AR. So if I change to AR it start changing language correct !!!

Comment: if you are changing language resource(using dropdown and code) than I think it will not download the resource and you will have same issue. But not sure as I have not tried changing language resource in code....
But to fix this issue you should use never in - manifest--->packaging(last tab)--->Generate app bundle to never. 
in this way all your app resouces will be dowloaded with the app

Comment: Lets see it will work or not

Answer (score 1):

When packaging for the store, your app is split up into bundles, which contain only the resources relevant for the device (installed languages, sized visual assets, etc.). When installing from the store, only the relevant bundles are downloaded.

You can disable it in the Manifest unter Packaging > Generate Bundle.

(Note: This option is no longer available in Win10...)

Comment: You did not told me benefit of it and will it solve my issue.

Comment: Benefit of bundling is a smaller App package to download/install for your users. Disabling it will result in a bigger package, but it will include all resources/assets, not just those relevant for the device. It "might" be the solution to your problem.